Connecting MIPI DSI 39 pin to 40-pin LCD touch display
My board is radxa zero 2 pro. It has 4-lane MIPI DSI connector with 39-Pin and 0.3mm pitch. MIPI pin details of radxa zero 2 pro:
| :-: | :-----------: |
| 1 | LCD_VCC |
| 2 | VDDIO_AO18 |
| 3 | NC |
| 4 | TDMB_D2 |
| 5 | NC |
| 6 | GND |
| 7 | MIPI_D0_N |
| 8 | MIPI_D0_P |
| 9 | GND |
| 10 | MIPI_D1_N |
| 11 | MIPI_D1_P |
| 12 | GND |
| 13 | MIPI_CLK_N |
| 14 | MIPI_CLK_P |
| 15 | GND |
| 16 | MIPI_D2_N |
| 17 | MIPI_D2_P |
| 18 | GND |
| 19 | MIPI_D3_N |
| 20 | MIPI_D3_P |
| 21 | GND |
| 22 | GND |
| 23 | TP_RESET |
| 24 | VCC3.3V |
| 25 | TOUCH_INT |
| 26 | TOUCH_I2C_SDA |
| 27 | TOUCH_I2C_SCL |
| 28 | GND |
| 29 | GND |
| 30 | LCD_VCC |
| 31 | LCD_VCC |
| 32 | GND |
| 33 | GND |
| 34 | VCC_LEDK |
| 35 | VCC_LEDK |
| 36 | NC |
| 37 | NC |
| 38 | VCC_LEDA |
| 39 | VCC_LEDA 

I have to interface this LCD touch display:
https://newhavendisplay.com/3-5-inch-ips-tft-mipi-interface-capacitive-touchscreen/
This LCD display has following specs for MIPI DSI: 40 pin FFC (0.5mm pitch 40-Conductor FFC)
Below are the differences in the LCD display and the radxa board:

LCD touch display has 40 pins. Radxa zero 2 pro has 39 MIPI DSI pins in connector.
Pitch in LCD touch display is 0.5mm, while in Radxa MIPI connector its  0.3mm

How to I interface both the above (LCD touch display and Radxa MIPI connector) ??? Kindly help with any leads or pointers ??
